# Perforce log in as someone else

Tags: perforce

In the doc's I'm reading: `To log in to Perforce automatically, you can save your password in a text file, and redirect p4 login to read from that file. For example, if you saved your password to a file called password.txt, the command would be:`

**Command:**

`p4 login < password.txt`

However I've created a new local account using the following commands:

```
p4 user -f test
p4 passwd perforce-bot
```

When I now wan't to login with `p4 login test < password.txt` it complains about "Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset".

How should I understand that? This operation works fine if I first do a `p4 login` (I'm an admin) and then run that snippet, it basically feels like sudo'ing as someone else, but I would want to use it without the need to login as my user first so I can run it as a cronjob on any machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two different commands:

- `p4 login`: authenticates the current user ($P4USER) by prompting for a password
- `p4 login USER`: authenticates an arbitrary other user IF already authenticated as a super user

Note also that if you run `p4 passwd perforce-bot`, you're setting the password for a user called `perforce-bot` (again, this is an admin command).

To temporarily switch the current user without resetting $P4USER, use the `-u` global flag:

```
p4 -u test user            # creates a new user called "test"
p4 -u test passwd          # sets the password for "test"
p4 -u test login           # login "test" via stdin password prompt
p4 -u test <any command>   # run any other command as "test"
```